# Import python modules in a completely different directory

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I am writing a script that automates the use of other scripts. I've set it up to automatically import other modules from `.py` files stored in a directory called `dependencies` using `importlib.import_modules()`

Originally, I had `dependencies` as a subdirectory of the root of my application, and this worked fine. However, it's my goal to have the `dependencies` folder stored potentially anywhere a user would like. In my personal example, it's located in my dropbox folder while my script is run from a different directory entirely.

I cannot for the life of me seem to get the modules to be detected and imported anymore and I'm out of ideas.

Would someone have a better idea of how to achieve this?

This is an example of the path structure:

`E:
|_ Scripts:
| |_ Mokha.py
|
|_ Dropbox:
| |_ Dependencies:
|   |_ utils.py`

Here's my code for importing: (I'm reading in a JSON file for the dependency names and looping over every item in the list)

`def importPythonModules(pythonDependencies):
    chdir(baseConfig["dependencies-path])
    for dependency in pythonDependencies:
        try:
            moduleImport = dependency
            module = importlib.import_module(moduleImport)
            modules[dependency] = module
            print("Loaded module: %s" % (dependency))
        except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
            print(e)
            raise Exception("Error importing python dependecies.")
    chdir(application_path)`

The error I get is `No module named 'utils'`

I've tried putting an **init**.py in both the dependencies folder, the root of my dropbox, and both at the same time to no avail.

This has got to be possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I solved it.

sys.path.append(baseConfig['dependencies-path'])

Not *super* happy with the solution but it'll work for now.